# jquery keyup event depend on id parameter

Tags: jquery

i am using jquery keyup method to convert letters to uppercase which is working now.but how can i add exception into so that my `txtEmail` id wont get converted into uppercase

```
<input runat="server" clientidmode="static" type="text" id="txtEmail" value="" />
 //Only this emaild should not get change to uppercase 

<input runat="server" clientidmode="static" type="text" id="txtAdd1" value="" />
```

jQuery :

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
```

i can not change HTML markup. i want to do it in jquery itself.

Comment: I believe it would be cleaner to use a special class and mark the input elements you DO want to convert, rather than adding exceptions all the time. You could for example do ```<input class="uppercase">```, then your selector would simply be ```$('.uppercase').keyup(...);```.

Comment: thought of implementing same but as i mentioned cant change markup

Comment: Oops, I missed that bit of your post. Never mind then. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$("input[type=text]").not('#txtEmail').keyup(function () {
```

---

also use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` lil faster.

---

<kbd>[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jagruti/ynuS3/)</kbd> by [jagruti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470576/jagruti)

Comment: @jagruti ty for the fiddle :) added your fiddle in answer .

Comment: Thanks a lot I in first answer there is no . before keyup so that i create fiddle for same.

Comment: @jagruti that's because of typing fast but corrected it soon .ty anyway :)